# DOM Node Inserted on Body Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I'm looking for a way to add some inline css to the body tag and another div in the page as the page loads to override some styles listed in the stylesheet which cannot be changed. The script itself forces the page to centre align but any onload event waits until the page has finished loading (with a left alignment) before centring it. I need the script to add this css as the page loads so the front end view is seemless.

I came across the DOMNodeInstered event but open to any ideas. I'm deploying the script through a tag manager so can only fire the script either in the head or in the body.

Really appreciate any help anyone can give.

Comment: Styles in a stylesheet can always be overriden. Please provide an example of what you want to override.

Comment: The stylesheet is setting the position of the body and the page wrapper div with an absolute position of left 0px. Below is some of what I've written to override the stylesheet.

`document.getElementById('page-body').style.position= 'relative';
document.getElementById('page-body').style.left= 'auto';
document.getElementById('page-body').style.top= 'auto';
document.getElementById('page-body').style.margin= '0px auto 0px auto';`

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want your style to be overriden, make sure you're setting the style as close to the element as possible, which is inline. Also make sure to add !important to it.

For example:

```
document.querySelector("body").style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

Comment: Thanks Mathijs. If I deploy this in the head, will the page be built with the updated inline styles?

Comment: You can attach it to an event like the onload event. This will execute when the page has loaded completely. You can use the window.onload event like so: `window.onload = function () {document.querySelector("body").style.backgroundColor = "red";}`

Comment: Sorry, this is the issue I'm having. If the event is executed once the page has loaded completely, the page will load left aligned before the script then center aligns it. I need a way to execute the script as the page is built.

Comment: In that case you wont need to attach it to an event, you can write it in the top of your body and it will execute when your body is being loaded.

Comment: Thank you. If I have the script in the head, how can I write it in immediately following the body tag?

Comment: You can document.write the script in your body if you cannot choose the location of the script in the first place.